# django models orm delete/update RETURNING values

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

При обновлении данных в таблице через ORM возвращается число измененных записей. К примеру запрос:

```
Books.objects.filter(state_id=4).update(state_id=2)
```

Можно ли как то сделать чтобы возвращались нужные мне колонки добавляя в запрос

`... RETURNING id`

Comment: `.values('id')` не работает?

Comment: Нет. Если бы было так просто то не написал бы. Много всего перерыл но ничего подходящего не нашел. Пока написал свой Manager для моделей который сначала выполняет SELECT а потом уже условия DELETE или UPDATE. Но это 2 запроса, а хотелось бы сделать через один с использованием RETURNING, так как запросы могут быть очень тяжелыми и долгими, думал уже в таких случаях из первого запроса получать id записей и потом условия обновления или удаления делать с ними, тогда второй запрос будет быстрым